# How to toggle the text in anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get back the old text in the anchor tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginBarHandle").click(function() {
        $("#myLink").text("Close");
     });
});
```

But If I add a if condition, the slider associated with it will not slide Up. Any other ways?

Comment: What do you want to toggle, Open/Close ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to toggle text in jquery is to use if/else condition like this:

```
if ($(this).text() == "Close")
       $(this).text("OtherText")
    else
       $(this).text("Close");
```

or hiding/showing elements conditionally. If your animation doesn't work, this means that something else is broken. just share your code.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to swap it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginBarHandle").click(function() {
        $("#myLink").text(function(_, text){
             return text== "Close" ? "Open" : "Close";
         });
     });
});
```